# How to build JAR from spark source code which is same as JAR available in spark downloads?

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, jar, apache-spark-mllib

I need to make few changes to the spark mllib random forest algorithm. I got the source code from https://github.com/apache/spark . I have built the JAR using maven but the JAR which I built misses some classes which are in the original MLLib JAR(SPARK Downloads).

I have built the code in linux machine using maven.

The command used to build was ./build/mvn -DskipTests clean package.

Original JAR is available in https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-mllib_2.11/2.4.3

The JAR built should be of size size 7.65MB . But I get a JAR of size 5.4MB named spark-mllib_2.12-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT .

Comment: Please share or provide the link to your "pom.xml". Then we can give check.

Comment: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/pom.xml  is the link to the MLLib pom.xml .                                          https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/pom.xml is the link to pom.xml of spark repository